# Upload a file through a webpage to mySql database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a HTML webpage with a form to upload a file. When you click submit I want to send the form to a php file where it will store it in my database.

Currently I use the reqular xmlHTTPRequest to send a GET request to my php files. This all works perfectly so I would prefer not to restructure my program.

Could someone give me some guidance as to how to do that? I tried to send the file as I sent other inputs (Text etc) but got a null value in the php.

Code:
The HTML is a simple input tag (this won't show it when I copy it in).

JavaScript:

```
var picture = document.getElementById("file").value;
generateAjaxRequest("type=insert&picutre="+picture")
```

AJAX:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(elementName).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/Controller.php);
xmlhttp.send();
```

PHP:

```
$file = @$_GET["file"];
$query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO table  (image) VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 's',$file);
stmtGetInfo($query);
```

When a file is uploaded a user will click submit which will call the Javascript. The javascript sends the file to the ajax which then sends it to the php file. I have only put up some of the code to demonstrate what is happening. All of the methods work for text entry etc.

Comment: let's see the code you have been using so far

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Please also add  your HTML form, including the form attribute

Comment: Is php.ini configured to allow file uploads? i.e. is file_uploads set to 'On'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to upload files using xmlHTTPRequest, these links can be usefull.

1. https://gist.github.com/ebidel/2410898
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest